# config(npm) throws configuration property not found but getConfigSources method logs correct object

Tags: typescript, node-config, nx.dev

I am trying to integrate `config` package in my nx.dev typescript project. I have a `config` directory at root level that contains default.json

```
{
  "server": { "port": 3001 }
}
```

in my `index.ts` I try

```
import { get, util } from 'config';

console.log(util.getConfigSources());
console.log(get('server'));
```

and get the following:

```
[
  {
    name: 'path to config file.. /config/default.ts',
    original: '{\n  "server": {\n    "port": 3001\n  }\n}',
    parsed: { server: [Object] }
  }
]

Error: Configuration property "server" is not defined
```

And everywhere it says this is all I need to hook it up but `get` function throws.

Comment: Were you able to solve this?

Comment: @MarkStosberg this was for a personal project and I haven't done much on it in a few months. There's an answer though, if it works do tell me I'll accept it.

Answer (score 0):

The node-config `get` method is designed-- and documented-- to be called as a method of a `config` object. Try using the documented import syntax:

```js
const config = require('config');
console.log(config.get('server'));
```

An object method can't be expected to work the same when called as a function in JavaScript. An object method has `this` bound to the object. A function does not, unless `bind()` has been explicitly called on the function to bind it to an object.